# Cannot import Config from yamlconf in usaddress-scourgify

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, spyder

I am planning to use usaddress-scourigfy to clean some addresses that I have.(https://github.com/GreenBuildingRegistry/usaddress-scourgify)
I had a lot of trouble installing it with pip in anaconda prompt, and ended up installing it by copy and pasting the files into my site packages by hand.

When I type import scourgify, I am given

```
File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scourgify\address_constants.py", line 
11, in <module>
from yamlconf import Config, ConfigError

ImportError: cannot import name 'Config'
```

I looked into yamlconf and cannot find anything named 'Config', or 'ConfigError' in there. I changed the code from

```
from yamlconf import Config, ConfigError
```

to

```
from config import Config, ConfigError
```

But that messes up the rest of the package.

Comment: Probably a result of your „manual“ install. You should ask how to install the package properly instead, describing the problems you had with it.

Comment: I agree with @flyx.